# How to change li tag when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I want to change li class feature as "active" when clicking on it. When it does, it opens a new page and li class is given as active. For example, the page can be opened wtih the tag named for Overview as defined li. When I click any of tag, the new page can be opened with li tag as active. I try to write some codes but I couldn't change the active of li

Here are my codes shown below.

Home Page

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.jsp">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="list_users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

User Page.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="index.jsp">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="list_users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
    // Nav bar change active status
    $(".nav li").on("click", function() {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

What I say is to change active of

when I click any of item based on

.

Normally, it shows like this

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="index.jsp">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="list_users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it really shows like this

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="index.jsp">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="list_users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

What I means is to show that javascipt code cannot work. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer. I solved it.

```
$(function(){
  var current_page_URL = location.href;
  $( "a" ).each(function() {
     if ($(this).attr("href") !== "#") {
       var target_URL = $(this).prop("href");
       if (target_URL == current_page_URL) {
          $('nav a').parents('li, ul').removeClass('active');
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
          return false;
       }
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the CSS [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) to solve this?

```
.nav li:active {
    // your style
}
```